# iOS5 CGAffineTransformMakeRotation doesn't work the second time I do it?

Tags: animation, ios5, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I have simple rotation transformation, combined with alpha, which works perfectly on the first call, but the rotation doesn't happen the second time (the user initiates this animation by tapping the screen).

Here is my basic animation function:

```
- (void) animateMe:(UIImageView *)myImage delay:(NSTimeInterval)dly
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                          delay:dly
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^(void){
                         myImage.alpha = 1.0;
                         myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         myImage.alpha = 0.0;
                  }];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the second time you want to rotate the view, it is already rotated by 180 degrees and the line:

```
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180.0);
```

is equivalent to:

```
myImage.transform = myImage.transform;
```

So you should do something like:

```
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myImage.transform, 180.0);
```

---

Note that the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) says that the rotation angle should be in radians an not degrees. So you probably should use `M_PI` instead of `180.0`.

Also, note that the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW105) says that `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` **must** be combined with `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`.

> **UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse**
>
> Run the animation backwards and forwards. Must be combined with the UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!  I'll give your suggestion a try and assign the check if it works, sounds like you might be right about that.  Very surprised that they would use radians -- seems like an awkward way to do it, but I see that's what the documentation says.

Comment: Ok, I took me a moment to realize that CGAffineTransformRotate() is a different function than CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()!  Your suggestion works, thanks.  Your links were very helpful, I'm learning a lot about the Affine transformations.

Comment: One additional comment, I've been reading documentation on block animation and it says that you can specify a repeat count in combination with UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse -- it is not required to combine with UIViewAnimationAutoRepeat.